# Como agrupar produtos por id e somar as quantidades total de cada produto vindos de um array json em php?

Tags: php, json

Preciso somar a quantidade de cada produto que foi vendido agrupando os mesmo por "id_produto" e somando suas quantidades. Ou seja, no exemplo logo abaixo tenho 4 pedidos que precisam printar na tela + - da seguinte forma:

```
Total qtd coca cola : 6
Total qtd moda catupiry : 11
Total valor coca cola: 24,00
Total valor moda catupiry: 55,00
```

Os dados estão salvos em um array json no banco de dados SQL.

```
[{"id_produto":"768","qtd":8,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"}]
[{"id_produto":"750","qtd":2,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"}]
[{"id_produto":"768","qtd":3,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"}]
[{"id_produto":"750","qtd":4,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"}]
```

Tentei varias forma já a uma semana e não consegui. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teste o seguinte código:

```
   $json = json_decode('[{"id_produto":"768","qtd":8,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"},
    {"id_produto":"750","qtd":2,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"},
    {"id_produto":"768","qtd":3,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"},
    {"id_produto":"750","qtd":4,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"}]', true);

    $final = array();
    foreach($json as $produto)
    {
      if(isset($final[$produto["id_produto"]]))
      {
         $final[$produto["id_produto"]]["quantidade"] += $produto["qtd"];
         $final[$produto["id_produto"]]["valor_uni"] += $produto["qtd"] * $produto["valor_uni"];
      }else{
           $final[$produto["id_produto"]]["quantidade"] = $produto["qtd"];
           $final[$produto["id_produto"]]["valor_uni"] = $produto["qtd"] * $produto["valor_uni"];
      }
    }

print_r($final);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [768] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 11
            [valor_uni] => 55
        )

    [750] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 6
            [valor_uni] => 24
        )

)
```

Comment: Seu código rodou de boa. Porém, quando uso o meu igual vem do banco assim:

$json = json_decode('[{"id_produto":"768","qtd":8,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"}] [{"id_produto":"750","qtd":2,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"}] [{"id_produto":"768","qtd":3,"valor_uni":"5.00","produto":"MODA COM CATUPIRY"}] [{"id_produto":"750","qtd":4,"valor_uni":"4.00","produto":"COCA-COLA LATA"}]', true);

ele dá um erro: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @DsDigital o seu código vem exatamente assim? 4 objetos de json?